# Passing data from javascript to ios

Tags: javascript, ios, parameters, uiwebview

I have a function in a javascript file that must pass the data (the date, start time and end time) to a function that builds the ios calendar. How can I do?

Functions javascipt:

```
function AddItemToCalendarDevice(startdatetime,enddatetime,title){

if (android){
      AndroidFunction.AddCalendarItemDateTime(startdatetime,enddatetime,title);     
}
else if (ios){
    //How can I do?
}
```

}

Functions ios:

```
 - (NSMutableArray *)fetchEvents
{
    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

    //Create the end date components
   NSDateComponents *tomorrowDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
   tomorrowDateComponents.day = 1;

   NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]   
               dateByAddingComponents:tomorrowDateComponents
                                                                toDate:startDate
                                                               options:0];
// We will only search the default calendar for our events
NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.defaultCalendar];

    // Create the predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate
                                                                  endDate:endDate
                                                                calendars:calendarArray];

// Fetch all events that match the predicate
NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate]];
NSLog(@"l'array di eventi è %@", events);

return events;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a javascript function that will create and then remove an iframe with target like "ios://YOUR_DATA_AS_AN_URL_ENCODED_STRING" and use your UIWebViewDelegate

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

to retrieve the call and do your work

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    NSString *url = [request.URL absoluteString];

    if ([url hasPrefix:@"ios:"]) {
        NSArray *array = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        NSLog(@"%@", array);
        // extract your data from the array            



        return NO;
    }
else {
    return YES;

}
```

javascript function:

```
function jsToNative(nativeCmd) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "ios:" + nativeCmd);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
}
```

Comment: an alternative would be to use the above method as a way to tell you native code "data are read" and then use UIWebView - (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script method to call javascript getters to retrieve your values

Comment: Can you do an example?Please

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript AddItemToCalendarDevice method, create a custom url that you can parse inside your web view delegate:

```
function AddItemToCalendarDevice(startdatetime,enddatetime,title){

    if (android){
        AndroidFunction.AddCalendarItemDateTime(startdatetime,enddatetime,title);     
    }
    else if (ios){
        window.load.href = "file://yourappname/AddCalendarEntry?starttime=" + startdatetime + "&endtime=" + enddatetime + "&title=" + title;
    }
```

}

Then in your Web View delegate, implement shouldStartLoadWithRequest:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSString *urlString = request.URL.absoluteString;

    if ([urlString hasPrefix:@"file://yourappname/AddCalendarEntry"])
    {
        // Parse out the query params
        NSDictionary *queryParams = [self parseQueryParams:[[request URL] query]];
        NSString *startTimeStr = [queryParams objectForKey:@"starttime"];
        NSString *endTimeStr = [queryParams objectForKey:@"endtime"];
        NSString *title = [queryParams objectForKey:@"title"];

        // Convert the start time and end time to NSDate
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"  // Change this to match your date format
        NSDate *startTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startTimeStr];
        NSDate *endTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endTimeStr];
        [dateFormatter release];

        // Add the event to the calendar
        eventStore=[[EKEventStore alloc] init];
        EKEvent *addEvent=[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
        addEvent.title = eventTitle;
        addEvent.startDate = startDate;
        addEvent.endDate = endDate;
        [addEvent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        // uncomment if you want to set an alarm
        // addEvent.alarms=[NSArray arrayWithObject:[EKAlarm   alarmWithAbsoluteDate:addEvent.startDate]];
        [eventStore saveEvent:addEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:nil];
        [eventStore release];
    }
    return YES;            
}


-(NSDictionary *)parseQueryParams:(NSString *)queryString
{
    NSArray *params = [queryString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *param in params)
    {
        NSArray *pair = [param componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString *key = [pair objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *value = [pair objectAtIndex:1];
        [dictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
    }
    NSDictionary *queryParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionary];
    [dictionary release];
    return queryParams;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but my request.URL.query  is "indexsessiondate=0&indexroom=1&indexsession=0", I did like in your example but the code analyzes the url of the page

Comment: My bad - that's what I get for writing code in my head...try using request.URL.absoluteString instead of request.URL.query. I'll edit the code above accordingly.

Comment: Also, make sure you escape any special characters in the javascript code - if your startdatetime or enddatetime contain a / or : for example, those characters will need to be percent-escaped before you put them into your URL.  I didn't include that in the example, but the code assumes the inputs are already sanitized.